# MIUI 8 extended icons

Tags: miui, xiaomi, themes

I have MIUI 8 installed on my smartphone.
 It looks great, however icons for non-stock apps look ugly. Is there any icon pack, so I can keep the stock theme, but have MIUI-style icons for popular third-party apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I've managed to do that:

1. You need to have a Xiaomi Designer Account, because MIUI 8 doen't allow installing custom themes unless you are a 'designer'
   You should go to http://designer.xiaomi.com/, sign up and enter valid    data. After a day or so you will be able to import *.mtz files from the default MIUI theme manager.
2. Download an icon pack from MultiRom ROM. You can find them here:
   https://multirom.me/read.php?tid=343 (download link is in first post, sorry for russian)
3. After that you should open a theme manager, go to themes and import downloaded file. The final step is to select these icons in 'components' menu in theme manager

Answer (score 0):

use something like polycon icon pack:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.thearclabs.polycon&hl=en

Comment: It doen't work with MIUI default launcher

Comment: maybe you can use nova launcher? i really like it and i think it's the best launcher out there in terms of all-round functionality and customizability

Answer (score 0):

**Install theme with extended icons**
There are themes available which contains more icons for MIUI8, search for the theme's name in your theme manager / theme store:

- [eXtended 8](http://zhuti.xiaomi.com/detail/f068e9a8-1bd1-48b0-a062-a35a5eef66e5) (1'000 icons visible for xiaomi.eu and official rom)
- [V8-extended-icons](http://V8-extended-Icons) (visible for chinese stable and beta)
- [MultiROM Icons V8](http://zhuti.xiaomi.com/detail/b35b4fc8-bcfb-4c11-89f5-0cec2643130f) (2'700 icons visible for chinese stable and beta)

**If you have root and a custom recovery, you can flash:**

- [MIUI v8 alpha rom icons](http://en.miui.com/thread-288534-1-1.html) (1'500 icons)
- [Mia Ex](https://xiaomi.eu/community/threads/icons-mia-ex-miui-icon-addon-extended-huge.36439/) (12'200 icons)
- [MIUI 8 icons](http://en.miui.com/thread-303222-1-1.html) (1'500 icons)

**Xposed module to enable MTZ import**
You can install Xposed framework for [MIUI (by solarwarez)](http://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/unofficial-xposed-miui-t3367634), and then load the module [RootToolsNeo](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.rarnu.tools.neo). This module allows you to have the "import MTZ" option in your Theme Manager, even without having a Designer account. "Theme Crack"

**Official Designer Account to import any MTZ file**
Another option is to apply with your Xiaomi Account as a Theme Designer. After your application has been granted, you will be able to import MTZ files that you've downloaded from anywhere.